# Posting array data to Mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an array of members data in a session

```
$session_mem_id = $_SESSION['mem_id'];
$member_data  = member_data($session_mem_id, 'mem_id', 'mem_email', 'mem_password', 'mem_address', 'mem_city', 'mem_postcode', 'mem_county', 'mem_country', 'mem_first_name', 'mem_last_name', 'password_recover', 'allow_email', 'admin', 'mem_tel');
```

And if I

```
var_dump($member_data);
die();
```

It outputs

```
array(14) { ["mem_id"]=> string(2) "11" ["mem_email"]=> string(26) "j.hfdfd2@gmail.com" ["mem_password"]=> string(8) "password" ["mem_address"]=> string(16) "41 fdrel Drive" ["mem_city"]=> string(9) "Maifdfd" ["mem_postcode"]=> string(8) "df14 4fS" ["mem_county"]=> string(4) "dfdf" ["mem_country"]=> string(14) "United Kingdom" ["mem_first_name"]=> string(4) "Bert" ["mem_last_name"]=> string(12) "dgfdgd" ["password_recover"]=> string(1) "0" ["allow_email"]=> string(1) "1" ["admin"]=> string(1) "1" ["mem_tel"]=> string(11) "07900186785" }
```

Now how do I parse this information to my function as they only things I can parse is mem_id, order_id and orderdate, everything else is blank

```
function createTransaction(){
    // Insert into the transactions table
    $query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO transactions (mem_id, OrderDate, Ship_Phone, Ship_Address, Ship_City, Ship_County, Ship_PostCode, Ship_Country) VALUES('{$_SESSION['mem_id']}', NOW(), '{$member_data["mem_tel"]}', '{$member_data['mem_address']}', '{$member_data['mem_city']}', '{$member_data['mem_county']}', '{$member_data['mem_postcode']}', '{$member_data['mem_country']}')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: use `PDO` or `mysqli-*` - re your question: pass the array as argument to your function.

Comment: Where are the data for order_id that you refer to as working?

Comment: @jtheman order_id is auto increment

Comment: You have a problem with non escaped quotes. `$member_data["mem_tel"]` would break the query string...

Comment: @jtheman it doesn't work with single quotes either

Comment: Rewrite your query using PDO and you will probably be fine. Apparently the array isn't empty.